# regex works in js but fails in html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I got a regex for matching URIs of YouTube

```
/^(https:\/\/youtu.be\/|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=|https:\/\/www.youtube-nocookie.com\/embed\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12})+/
```

it works well in js

```js
/^(https:\/\/youtu.be\/|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=|https:\/\/www.youtube-nocookie.com\/embed\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12})+/.test('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZP1wGptlUE&list=RDT4X7Ev7RIZA&index=2')
// true
```

but why it fails in html input[pattern] ?

**Please match the requested format**

```js
function handle(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handle">
  <input placeholder="YouTube URI"
      type="url"
      pattern="^(https:\/\/youtu.be\/|https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=|https:\/\/www.youtube-nocookie.com\/embed\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12})+" 
      value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZP1wGptlUE&list=RDT4X7Ev7RIZA&index=2"
      required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, _ and - and possibly some more characters are allowed in video id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML input patterns have an implicit `$` at the end, meaning that it expects to match the *entire* input.

You're not accounting for the `&list=RDT4X7Ev7RIZA&index=2`, so it's failing.

You can add something like `(\&.*)?` to fix it

Comment: And an implicit `^` at the start